# Jasperreport Subrelatório sobrepõe field

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

Boa tarde pessoal,
Estou tendo um problema no jasper reports que sei como resolver. Criei um relatório onde eu tenho uma lista de perguntas (fields) e cada pergunta possui uma lista de alternativa (sub relatório), acontece que se a pergunta for maior do que a linha a mesma faz a quebra automática, através da opção "Strech With Overflow". O problema é justamente nessa quebra de linha, ela fica atrás do sub relatório de alternativa. Alguem sabe como devo fazer para o sub relatório acompanhar a quebra da linha?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, coloquei posição tipo float no subreport e funcionou. Obrigado!